# How to have a centered layout with border (background-image), and footer sticked to the bottom?

Tags: html, css

I've lost alot of time to try to make this work, but with no success.
What I want is to have a div footer and to have a border around the whole website has I use a centered layout of 960px.

I've based myself on two tutorials: [CSS and round corners: Boxes with curves](http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/css-round-corners-boxes.shtml) and [How to Use the Sticky Footer Code](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html)

What happens is if I define a min-height:100% the footer is ok, but the border does not goes all the way down if a scroll is needed, if I set an height:100% the footer does not stay down but the border is ok.

Can anyone help?

The main html is:

```
<div id="border">
   <div class="content">...</div>
   <div class="footer">...</div>
</div>
```

And css is:

```
#border
{
   background: url("../Content/Images/border.png") repeat-y;
   width:978px;
   margin:auto;
   /*min-height:100%;*/
   height: 100%;
}


.footer
   {
    height: 116px;
    width: 960px;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        background-image: url("../Content/Images/footer_background.png");
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        position: relative;
        margin-top: -116px;
        clear: both;
       }
       .content
       {
          min-height:100%;
          width:960px;
          margin:auto;
          background-color: #EAFFE6;
       }
```

Comment: Tested this out in Chrome and Firefox.  Everything seems to work.  Where are you seeing it display wrong?

Comment: Tested it in IE9 and it crashed my browser :-/ (probably unrelated)

Comment: @Zach L. What I see wrong is, if you have more content than the screen, so you can scrolldown, when you scroll down, the border doesn't go all the way down.

Comment: I've had better success with Ryan Fait's sticky footer layout. You might give it a try: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: @Brandon i've already read that article too, thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use the #border div as 960px width and then add the background attribute with the border to the entire body:

```
body
{
   background: url("../Content/Images/border.png") repeat-y;
}
```